# NSMutableString access problem

Tags: iphone, xcode, global-variables, nsmutablestring

So I'd like to access and display a formatted date outside my function.  For the date format I am using `NSDateFormatter` which works fine..

My function (`didFinishUpdatesSuccessfully`) performs some action and if successful displays an `UIAlertView` which includes the formatted date. All that works fine..

```
- (void) didFinishUpdatesSuccessfully {

    //--- Create formatted date
    NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY - hh:mm:ss a"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];     // dateString contains the current date as a string

    [dateFormatter release];


    //--- UIAlertView
    NSString *title = @"The update has been performed!";

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: title
                                                    message: dateString
                                                   delegate: nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle: [FileUtils appResourceForKey:@"UPDATE_GENERAL_BUTTON_TITLE_OK"]
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

    //--- create new string
    // NSMutableString* lastUpdated = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dateString];

}
```

I now want to write the value of `dateString` into a global `NSString` or `NSMutableString`  and access it somewhere else in the code, e.g. another function etc..

I thought about creating a `NSMutableString` like this:
`NSMutableString* lastUpdated = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dateString];` and to access `lastUpdated` somewhere else, but ouside of this function `lastUpdated` is empty... Can you help?  Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableString* lastUpdated = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dateString];
```

If you do that, you're declaring a local variable named `lastUpdated`. Even if there's another global variable with the same name, this local one will hide the global variable for as long as it's in scope (the life of your function).

To make this work, you need to declare a global `lastUpdated` somewhere outside of any function or method, probably near the top of a .m file:

```
NSMutableString *lastUpdated;
```

You can then access that variable from anywhere in the .m file. If you want to access it in other .m files, you'll want to add an extern declaration in the corresponding header (.h) file:

```
extern NSMutableString *lastUpdated;
```

With that declaration, you can use `lastUpdated` in any file that includes that header file.

Two things to know:

1. This is basic C stuff, so if it seems unfamiliar, you should review scope rules for C. Know the difference between a global variable, a static variable, a local variable, an instance variable (okay, plain old C doesn't have those), and a parameter.
2. Global variables are horrible. Don't trust anybody who tells you otherwise. I offer the advice above to help solve your immediate problem, but a better solution would be to figure out how to refactor your code so that you can avoid the need for a global variable. (And IMO a singleton isn't the answer, either. Singletons used just to access global data aren't much more than fancy-pants global variables.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Well, I don't really like to use global variables and I do agree with the comments made about this... What I want is to retain and display the 'lastUpdate' value (the date of the last successful action somewhere before the UIAlertView fires the currentDate (now) so a user can decide not to update if it doesn't make sense... I guess I could add a subview with a label in 'didFinishUpdatesSuccessfully'. the problem here though is that the labels will be stacked on top of each other with the new value... Does that make sense? Any other idea?

Comment: It's hard to tell you how to reorganize your code without knowing some more about it, like where `-didFinishUpdatesSuccessfully` lives. Since it sounds like a delegate method, I'll guess that it's in a view controller. So, I'd guess that you probably want to store the date of the last update somewhere (maybe NSUserDefaults) where the controller can access it. Then let the view controller get the date, turn it into a string, and set the value of an existing label to that string. The view controller is in charge of the view, so it should know how to find the label.

Comment: Thanks Caleb, You are guessing right. It is a delegate in a view controller. To store the value in NSUserDefaults seems  reasonable. I now have to figure out how to do just that. Any snippert available?  Thanks

Comment: `[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] setObject:currDate forKey:@"lastUpdatedDate"];` There's a [whole document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/UserDefaults.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i) on the subject. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should retain the string like.

```
NSMutableString* lastUpdated;
lastUpdated = [[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dateString] retain];
```

Now try to access in outside.

Comment: If those two lines are meant to appear next to each other you haven't solved the problem. The second line only makes sense inside a method or function. If the first line also appears within that method or function, `lastUpdated` is a local variable. To make it global, the first line must be outside the scope of any method or function. However, you're right that the string needs to be retained. Figuring out who is supposed to retain the string and who is supposed to release it is tricky if the string is a global; count that as one more reason not to use a global.